# Is it possible for a program to in a sense 'autocomplete' the name of a folder from what it starts with?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a program that digs inside the Local App Data folder of another program, pulls out some files, and then pushes them to Azure Blob Storage. I've already developed the rest of the program, but the intent of the application is to be as brainless as possible for the user- just a simple double click and the files have been uploaded.

At the moment the program requires manual input to find the correct folder in Local App Data. The Problem lies in that the name of the folder isn't always completely constant.

The folder's name *always* starts with com.company.propelics, followed by a series of randomized numbers and characters. I've already checked and there's no way to reproduce the randomization for each user. Within that folder, the folder structure is always constant- so the program would never have an issue finding the files once the original folder is found.

Is there a way to either scan the folders in Local App Data for the subfolders that will always exist, or take what is constant (com.company.propelics) and select the folder with that in the name?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> candidates = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        "com.company.propelics*");
```

Then

```
var folderPath = candidates.FirstOrDefault();
```

or something more complicated if there's disambiguation to perform...

Comment: Attempting, will report back

Comment: Enumeration yielded no results, It's looking in local app data correctly, just not selecting the com.company.propelics folder

Comment: @Bright You've definnitely got the `*` on the end of the 2nd parameter, and `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` resolves to correct folder?

Comment: I totally didn't have the asterisk. Works like a charm now, Thank you so much!